# How to get a struct array to an IntPtr?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

C++ function prototype is;

```
/************************************************************************
parameters[in]: 
    void *handle,
    char *jpeg_buf,
    jpeg_buf jpeg_buf
parameters[out]:
    listSize:   result list size, max <= 1000;
    list:       result
************************************************************************/

int getInfo(void *handle,unsigned char* jpeg_buf, unsigned int jpeg_len, int& list_size, Info *info_list);
```

C++ types;

```
typedef struct
{
    int dot_x;
    int dot_y;
} Attr;


typedef struct
{
    int left;
    int top;
    int right;
    int bottom;
} Rect_S;


typedef struct
{
    Rect_S rect;
    Attr attr;
} Info;
```

C# DLL import;

```
[DllImport("sample.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern int getInfo(IntPtr handle, byte[] jpeg_buf, uint jpeg_len, out int listSize, out IntPtr List);
```

Structures are in C#;

```
internal struct Attr
    {
        public int dot_x;
        public int dot_y;
    };

    internal struct Rect_S
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    };

    internal struct Info
    {
        public Rect_S rect;
        public Attr attr;
    };
```

C# GetInfo Function;

```
public Info[] getInfo(byte[] scan0)
    {
        Info[] retVal = null;
        IntPtr structPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        int size;

        int ret = EFEngine.getInfo(this.Engine, scan0, (uint)scan0.Length, out size, out structPtr);

        if (ret >= 0)
        {
            retVal = new Info[size];
            int sizePointerInfo = Marshal.SizeOf(new EFaceInfo());
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                retVal[i] = (Info)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(structPtr.ToInt64() + (i * sizePointerInfo)), typeof(Info));
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

I get an error as "Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." when call the "Marshal.PtrToStructure".

What is it in wrong?

C++ test code;

```
int getInfoTest(void *handle, unsigned char* jpeg_buf, unsigned int jpeg_len, int& list_size, FaceInfo *face_rect_list)
{
    int nSizeNum = 0;
    Info* List = new Info[32];
    int nRet = getInfo(handle, jpeg_buf, jpeg_len, nSizeNum, List);
    if (nRet != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: getInfo failed\n");
    }
    delete[] List;
    delete[] jpeg_buf;

    return nRet;
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

As happened at your previous question, the information provided in the question is incomplete. As I tried to explain to you there, a C++ prototype does not fully specify the semantics of a C++ function. As I explained to you before, you should include those semantics, or at least some example C++ code to call the function.

However, it seems very likely that the problem is the final parameter. The caller is expected to allocate the memory and pass its address to the function. It looks very much like this final parameter is in fact an array. Working on that assumption, the p/invoke declaration should be:

```
[DllImport("sample.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern int getInfo(IntPtr handle, byte[] jpeg_buf, 
    uint jpeg_len, ref int listSize, [Out] Info[] List);
```

You would call the function like this:

```
int listSize = ...; // you have to somehow work out what to put here
Info[] List = new Info[listSize];
int retval = getInfo(handle, jpeg_buf, jpeg_len, ref listSize, List);
// check retval
```

Of course, since the list size parameter is passed by reference that would suggest that the function can tell you how large an array is needed. So perhaps the call sequence should be:

```
int listSize = 0;
int retval = getInfo(handle, jpeg_buf, jpeg_len, ref listSize, null);
// check retval
Info[] List = new Info[listSize];
int retval = getInfo(handle, jpeg_buf, jpeg_len, ref listSize, List);
// check retval
```

Comment: List size and list are stored c++ function. If i am not wrong, your sample is related to send to c++ function. if i chanced my code as your sample, couldnt call getInfo(). Also i added function information to my question.

Comment: Exactly the same is happening here as at your previous question. You have to understand that you have not yet specified how to call the function. Once again, please show example C++ code that calls the function if you cannot give the semantics of the function in another way.

Comment: The dll is not mine and i got it as compiled dll.

Comment: Ask whoever supplied it to give you the necessary information

Comment: It is my big mistake. I am sorry. I didnt take an error when i calling getInfo. I took error on Marshal.PtrToStructure. I realized already.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the code in my answer did not match the DLL. Although as I said I cannot be 100% sure.

Comment: Also your code is running. But listSize is returned 1 but all array item are zero.

Comment: Do you think the problem is in the C# code? Where is the documentation that states how to call the function, and shows that values other than zero are to be expected? Did you check the return value?

Comment: The C# codes looks like clearly. Just i am not sure the structures could match each others. If we can not solve with this structure, what is your suggestion that we should change?

Comment: I checked return value. And return value and list size is proper. Only all values in structure array items are zero.

Comment: And you think that the problem is that the pinvoke is wrong? What evidence do you have for that? How can you check the return value if you don't have any documentation? How do you know the list size if proper if you don't have any documentation? Or do you have documentation that we cannot see? Again, we are here to answer the questions that you ask rather than solve your problem.

Comment: I could test this function with same parameters in C++ and all return values are same. Just structure array is stored array. But in C# was zero.

Comment: I have repeatedly asked for example C++ code. You have it. But won't show it. Why won't you let me help you?

Comment: I have one idea though. Formally the array needs the `[Out]` attribute. My answer shows that now. I omitted it because I expected the marshaller to pin the array. But perhaps that does not happen. So add that. It is the right thing to do in any case.

Comment: i am sorry, i misunderstood that you want to source code. it is not at me. i edited my question for calling test code in c++.

Comment: Thank you for adding the C++ example code. I am sure that the code in my answer matches the C++.

Comment: The code in your answering is running. I had another a big mistake in my codes.